# A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis

Tags: keras

I try to train Unet neural network from zhixuhao, I submit to the input of the image 512x512 but I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "unet.py", line 168, in <module>
    myunet.train()
    File "unet.py", line 159, in train
    model.fit(imgs_train, imgs_mask_train, batch_size=1, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1, shuffle=True, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
    File "C:\Users\mimozzza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
    File "C:\Users\mimozzza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
    File "C:\Users\mimozzza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 138, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (256, 256, 3) but got array with shape (512, 512, 3)
```

Here is the code:

```
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    print ("conv1 shape:"),conv1.shape
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    print ("conv1 shape:"),conv1.shape
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    print ("pool1 shape:"),pool1.shape

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    print ("conv2 shape:"),conv2.shape
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    print ("conv2 shape:"),conv2.shape
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    print ("pool2 shape:"),pool2.shape

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    print ("conv3 shape:"),conv3.shape
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    print ("conv3 shape:"),conv3.shape
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    print ("pool3 shape:"),pool3.shape

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4, up6], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3, up7], axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2, up8], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1, up9], axis=3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model
```

I looked at other discussions on this topic and realized that the error might be related to the resolution of the image, but my files are the same resolution that was supposed to be zhixuhao initially.
Tell me, what's the problem, and how can I fix it?

PS:
I use keras version 1.0.0, and also use the latest version of the code from GitHub, I use the version on October 24, 2017.

Comment: Looking at the structure of your code, shouldn't `merge9` be concatenating `conv1` and `up9`? You are concatenating with `up7`.

Comment: @xdurch0 Thanks for the comment, but the problem did not dare

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, in the code images were specified with a resolution of 256x256, although I tried to learn from the 512x512 images.